# XSL-FO body-start()

Tags: xsl-fo

From this page - http://www.learn-xsl-fo-tutorial.com/Blocks-Inlines.cfm#h1.4

'The list-item-body FO contains the actual content of the list item. **It often takes the start-indent attribute with the value of body-start(), indicating that the body of the list item should start at the beginning of the list-item-body box.'**

I have searched for a more understandable statement but I have failed. So can someone explain the part in bold above with more words, please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you probably know, each `fo:list-item` has an `fo:list-item-label` and an `fo:list-item-body`, where the label is usually something like a bullet and the body contains the actual content (text, etc.).

The body's `start-indent` attribute governs the indent between the label and the body in *inline-progression-dimension*, which in normal circumstances means the horizontal direction (although this can be changed).

Since `body-start` calculates the position one usually needs anyway, one would imagine that it is the default value. But as this link http://www.renderx.com/tutorial.html states, `body-start` "is not a default value; don't forget to specify it on each `<fo:list-item-body>`".

Answer (score 0):

The `start-indent` attribute specifies where the `list-item-body` should start. The function `body-start()` returns the relative position of the start point of the body.

The way I interpret this is that it's basically saying start the indent from the point of the `list-item-body` with no additional indent.

Not sure if this is any better an explanation or not.

Answer (score 0):

`start-indent` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#start-indent) specifies the relative offset in the 'start' direction of the current area relative to its reference area. As @Dabbler said, most of the time for most people, this is the horizontal left indent relative to the edge of the page region or edge of the area generated by an `fo:block-container`, etc.  Its initial value is 0pt, and it is inherited.

`start-indent="body-start()"` is both a convenience feature and a bit of magic.

It's a convenience feature because you just need to set `provisional-distance-between-starts` on the `fo:list-block` and remember the `start-indent="body-start()"` on every `fo:list-item-body` and the formatter will handle the rest.

The first part of the magic is that the `body-start()` value incorporates both the `start-indent` of the containing `fo:list-block` and the `provisional-distance-between-starts` value of the containing `fo:list-block`. You (or I, at least) don't want to have to worry about the `start-indent` of the whole list when indenting the `fo:list-item-body`.

The second part is that `body-start()` automatically includes any effect from a float on the start side of the list pushing the whole list, or maybe just the current list item, away from the start edge of the reference area.

The last sleight of hand is that `fo:list-item-body` doesn't generate any areas of its own, so `start-indent` doesn't even apply to it. You set it on the `fo:list-item-body` so that the value is inherited by the `fo:block`, etc., contained by the `fo:list-item-body`.